# What kind of useful function will return a char taking a char and its index in a string?

Tags: c

I cant explain any better so here's this prototype:

```
char    *my_function(char *str, char (*f)(int, char))
```

What I'm trying to figure out is what f would stand for in here, given that the int is an index and char is str[index]. For even more clarity:

```
f(index, str[index]);
```

What could this be apart from my crappy test f that returns str[index] + index? Is there any USEFUL function with such prototype out there?

Comment: maybe used to change vowels (or some type of character) at odd indexes (or some type of indexing rule)

Comment: @pmg Thanks this sounds plausible at least!

Comment: Can you inspect the code that calls `my_function`? Then you'll see what function is supplied for `f`. Otherwise have a look on how the `f` function is used in `my_function`. As you didn't provide more relevant code your guess is as good as ours.

Comment: A function cannot possibly know that a char is taken from some string which the function doesn't get to see. All it has is some char and some integer. I cannot imagine any genuinely useful, non-arbitrary operation `f` can perform.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thanks, you have a point. I've updated my post

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Same, i cannot think of anything that this would be good for, but apparently this is what the task is about, as my solution in the post was evaluated as correct.

Comment: Unless you have access to some actual code that calls `my_function` the only thing you can do is guess. But anyway this looks like some really fishy design to me.

Comment: If you have a task, **post it verbatim**.

Comment: Maybe it's a one-way function?  `f(i, c) = key[memchr(key[i % KEYLEN], c, KEYLEN)]` for example?  I could see such a function being used to generate a salt based on the password itself, which would then be appended to that password before hashing the resulting string and storing the hash in a DB.  This way, there's no need to store the salt applied to the password in a separate DB field.  A little more CPU time results in increased password security, and unless an attacker knows the exact details of that algorithm, they won't be able to compute the hash, assuming the algorithm isn't too simple

Comment: `Is there any USEFUL function with such prototype out there?` It could be an internal function used to obfuscate the string (like [memfrob](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Obfuscating-Data.html#Obfuscating-Data)) that also "tries" to protect against "decrypting" parts of the data. For example `f(i, c) = c ^ ((i + 10) % 255)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A useful pair of functions would be to lightly encrypt/decrypt the string.

As the goal includes working with a *string*, some useful ideas:

- As an *index to a string*, better to use `size_t` than `int`.  `int` is insufficient for long strings.

  ```
  // char (*f)(int, char)
  char (*f)(size_t offset, char ch)
  ```
- With `dst[i] = f(i, str[i]);`, to maintain *string* length, `f(offset, 0)` should return 0 and `f(offset, non_zero)` should return non-zero.
- If used to encrypt/decrypt, it would make sense that the function maps the 256 different inputs to 256 different results.

Example:

```
char encrypt(size_t offset, char ch) {
  if (ch == 0) return 0;

  // Simplistic encryption for illustration
  offset = offset%255 + 1;  
  ch += offset;
  if (ch == 0) ch = offset;

  assert(ch);
  return ch;
}
```